# Swift 4 delegates and passing textfield data

Tags: swift, delegates

I am trying to make an app using the GoogleBooks API where I can use either a title or author or both to search for books. I am currently just working on the delegate portion to be able to pass the search terms to the results table view. However, I am getting errors with the variables I am using being let constants but I have them declared as var so I'm not sure where I am messing up.

This is the UIViewController code for the view with the two search boxes and the button:

```
import UIKit

protocol ViewControllerDelegate: class {
    func searchInput(_ titleFromSearch: String?, authorFromSearch: String?)
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var titleFromSearch: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var authorFromSearch: UITextField!

    weak var delegate: ViewControllerDelegate?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        titleFromSearch.delegate = self
        authorFromSearch.delegate = self
    }

    override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event:
        UIEvent?) {
        super.touchesEnded(touches, with: event)
        titleFromSearch.resignFirstResponder()
        authorFromSearch.resignFirstResponder()
    }
}

extension ViewController: UITextFieldDelegate {
    func fieldsDidEndEditing(_ titleEntered: UITextField, authorEntered:
        UITextField) {
        if let delegateController = delegate {
            delegateController.searchInput(titleFromSearch.text,
                                           authorFromSearch: authorFromSearch.text)
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the code for the TableViewController that I have set up for the results to be displayed in.

```
import UIKit
import GoogleBooksApiClient

class SearchResultsTableViewController: UITableViewController {
    var titleFromSearch: String?
    var authorFromSearch: String?

    var data = [Volume]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let session = URLSession.shared
        let client = GoogleBooksApiClient(session: session)

        let req = GoogleBooksApi.VolumeRequest.List(query: "Google")

        let task: URLSessionDataTask = client.invoke(
            req,
            onSuccess: { [weak self] volumes in
                self?.data = volumes.items
                self?.tableView.reloadData()
            },
            onError: { error in
                print("\(error)") }
        )
        task.resume()
    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection
        section: Int) -> Int {
        return data.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt
        indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell",
                                                 for: indexPath)

        let item = data[indexPath.row]
        cell.textLabel?.text = item.volumeInfo.title
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = item.volumeInfo.authors.first

        return cell
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        super.prepare(for: segue, sender: sender)
        if let destination = segue.destination as? ViewController {
            destination.delegate = self
        }
    }
}
```

Here is where I get the let constant error is with these two assignment statements:

```
extension SearchResultsTableViewController: ViewControllerDelegate {
    func searchInput(_ titleFromSearch: String?, authorFromSearch: String?)
    {
        titleFromSearch = titleFromSearch
        authorFromSearch = authorFromSearch
    }
}
```

I added all the code because as I said I am new to iOS and I'm not sure where this error stems from in the code.

Answer (score 1):

In the two lines causing your errors:

```
titleFromSearch = titleFromSearch
authorFromSearch = authorFromSearch
```

you are attempting to assign the parameters to themselves. You want to set the parameter values to your properties of the same name. To do this, add `self.` to the property references:

```
self.titleFromSearch = titleFromSearch
self.authorFromSearch = authorFromSearch
```

Comment: I gotcha, thanks! I didn't realize that. Would you have any suggestions about the delegate? I made the change you suggested and my inputs dont cross over and get set to those variable. I appreciate any help

Comment: Your `fieldsDidEndEditing` isn't any known method of the `UITextFieldDelegate` protocol so it will never be called.

Comment: I cannot use textFieldDidEndEditing though because that protocol only has one parameter right and i need two? In that case would i need to create my own protocol for this?

Comment: You can't make up methods for `UITextFieldDelegate`. `textFieldDidEndEditing` will be called for the specific text field that has just ended editing.

Comment: So i need two versions of the textfieldDidEndEditing because i have two textfields and i need to be able to differentiate them correct?

Comment: No, there is only one. You can't have two. There is no need to for two. The `textField` parameter tells you which text field just ended editing.

Comment: Okay, so with that being said i believe my entire delegate is set up wrong. Could you give me one last piece of help, Which class should my protocol be established in? I thought from an example that i found online it would be in my first view controller with the textfields and the button but i just realized that i didnt even have the segue function implemented and it is throwing errors because im assuming it is in the same class. Therefore if i am correct to this point, my protocol should be declared in my other view, SearchResults